# Nginx: Getting OAuth2 token

Tags: nginx, oauth-2.0

We have an architecture where all of our micro services are secured by a JWT token.  The token is provided by an identity server based on IdentityServer4 (https://identityserver.io).  The services are behind an Nginx reverse proxy. This works well to secure anything that is accessible to the outside (partner API, Vue.js applications etc).

There is a set of endpoints that need to get an exception for example webhook endpoints from external services that don't need to do the auth handshake with us.

We'd love to use Nginx reverse proxy and somehow let Nginx get a Bearer token for certain routes.  Does anyone know of a plugin like that?  There is a ton of literature on how to get Nginx to verify the token, but not to generate one.